# SYMFONY2 How to add many tags and categories in posts

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, tags, categories

I have a problem with Symfony2. I want add to posts in database tag name and category name but I can't :/ I have table 'tag' and 'category' in database. I reads tags and cat from database and display option for user(checkbox fields). When I check more than one position in database I have one position. How to do it?

Here is a picture that shows what I want to do: http://www.fotosik.pl/pokaz_obrazek/521ca3aab7103337.html

I try for example (is postType.php) :

```
$builder->add('tags', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PortfolioAdminBundle:Tag',
                'property' => 'name',
                'required' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
    ));
```

in entity:

```
public function __toString() {
     return (string)$this->getId();
}
```

and i try change type field tag and cat in database on string and int. I haven't idea how should do it :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using the appropriate type for tags. If I understand correctly, you want to add more than one tag for each post.
If I am correct, you can't do that with entity because it allows only one entity to be linked.
What you need to use is the collection type.

There is info on how to use it [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/collection.html) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedding-a-collection-of-forms)

Comment: When I use 'collection' in my form I have only title filed. I tried to use like this: [link](http://symfony2-document.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) and my filed 'taga' in view is only the taga and no option.

Comment: You need to create a form for your tags. Then use a collection of tags. If you use _collection_ without giving it a type, it won't work